# Multiple condition in one function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I'm recreating this kind of module on my app
[Ant Design Calendar](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0010) but I have multiple functions to call inside `dateCellRender`. How can I execute based on what's being called? It always execute the `holidayListDay` even if I haven't called it.

This is the component I'm call `dateCellRender` to assign each date in the calendar

```
<Calendar
  dateCellRender={dateCellRender}
  monthCellRender={monthCellRender}
  onPanelChange={changeCalendarMode}
/>
```

```
const dateCellRender = value => {
  let holidayListDay = getHolidayListDay(value);
  let employeeStartLeave = getEmployeeStartLeave(value);

  if(holidayListDay) {
    //execute code here

  } else if(employeeStartLeave) {
    //execute code here

  }

};
```

Here are the codes I'm calling above

```
const getHolidayListDay = value => {
  let holidayListDay = [...isHolidayDay];

  const calendarDates = value.toString();
  const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  return (
    holidayListDay.find(
      item =>
        moment(item.holidayDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == formatCalendarDates
    ) || []
  );
};
```

```
const getEmployeeStartLeave = value => {
 let employeeLeaves = [...isEmployeeLeave];

 const calendarDates = value.toString();
 const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 const filteredData = [].concat
  .apply([], employeeLeaves)
  .filter(item => item.startDate === formatCalendarDates);

 return filteredData;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your `getHolidayListDay()` function always returns a `true`ish value (an empty array evaluates to `true`).

Try changing the `if` to:

```
  if(holidayListDay && holidayListDay.length ) {
    //execute code here

  } else if(employeeStartLeave) {
    //execute code here

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in function return. If your function is returning array then you have to check array length. Because, in `if` condition, empty array always true. such as,

```
var test = [];
if(test)
    console.log('condition is true'); //it will output 'condition is true'

if(test && test.length>0)
    console.log('condition is false') //It will output nothing
```

For your code. If both `holidayListDay , employeeStartLeave` functions are returning array then you have to check like below:

```
if(holidayListDay && holidayListDay.length ) {
    //your code
} else if(employeeStartLeave && employeeStartLeave) {
   //your code
}
```